# BIND9 , restrict RNDC controls to specific views

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, rndc

I have a BIND9 installation where the zones are partitioned in different views.
I'd like to restrict the RNDC controls to this specific views.

Example: I want a RNDC client to be allowed to delete zones from view-A, but not from view-B.

Is it possible to implement such a configuration in BIND?

If not: any suggests for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe that the [control channel](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2574310) has any means of fine-grained access control.

One solution could be to implement a separate service that has rndc access and which has the desired user access control built in. (Eg some set of REST endpoints or whatnot that the clients can use.)